# Connecting any device to wired Keyboard USBs makes it stop working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, usb

I have an [Apple Keyboard with Numeric Keypad](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB110LL/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-english-usa) and a MacBook Pro (early 2015) with Yosemite (10.10.5).

This keyboard comes with two 2.0 USB ports, which, as per own product description, states:

> enable you to connect your mouse as well as a high-speed peripheral such as a digital camera or printer.

Every time I connect *anything* to these ports, the keyboard stops working (and of course, the connected device won't work either in almost all cases).

I tried different USB flash drives from different brands and sizes (1GB, 8GB), 1TB external drive, charge my headphones.. nothing.

Is there anything to be done in order to make the USB ports work in MacBook Pro (a hidden "use full power on usb" hidden feature perhaps)?

---

**Oddity:** One thing I discovered while testing was that if I plug iPhone on the right slot then the external hdd on the left, keyboard will work while hdd mounts and iPhone charges. But if I only plug one of them (hdd, headphones, etc), keyboard dies. I tested once in iMac and worked fine though. Is it broken perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I think the keyboard is not usb upward compatible so you might need to pay attention to USB 2 or USB 3 connection.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to comment on any post.

Comment: @Tetsujin There is a very short answer here. I've edited it to show the answer and then the "try and notice 3/2" as clarification. It might not be the right answer or the full answer, but making it a comment seems worse than editing it.

Comment: Hmm though my 1TB external drive is USB3, my iPhone (6+) is 2.0, as all flash drives (they are like 4 years old, probl they are 1.1). And 2/3 wouldn't apply to the headphone (wired beats studio 2) 'cause is just charging. Funny that as I posted, having iPhone and HDD at same time made both work. But any alone doesn't. Maybe the issue is specifically in the keyboard usb hub, not energy related?